# Isolated testing of a presenter nested under a model namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have the following object structure in a Rails app:

```
# app/models/model_a/model_b/model_c.rb
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
    class ModelC < ActiveRecord::Base
    end
  end
end

# app/presenters/model_a/model_b/presenter_for_model_c.rb
class ModelA::ModelB::PresenterForModelC
end
```

Now, when I want to test PresenterForModelC in isolation with RSpec, I don't want to have to `require 'spec_helper'` in order to have a fast running test (à la  [Corey Haines](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bNn6M2vqxHE) or [Gary Bernhardt](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/test-isolation-and-refactoring)), so instead I'm trying to load my presenter directly:

```
# spec/presenters/model_a/model_b/presenter_for_model_c_spec.rb
require_relative '../../../app/presenters/model_a/model_b/presenter_for_model_c'
describe ModelA::ModelB::PresenterForModelC do
end
```

However, this fails with:

```
uninitialized constant ModelA (NameError)
```

I can't just create a stubbed out structure like:

```
# spec/presenters/model_a/model_b/presenter_for_model_c_spec.rb
class ModelA
  class ModelB
  end
end
require_relative '../../../app/presenters/model_a/model_b/presenter_for_model_c'
```

since that would cause a problem when I run the full suite, since the classes would not be inheriting from the same parent when the model got loaded. Similarly, I can't use modules (for the same reason). I also want to avoid:

```
# spec/presenters/model_a/model_b/presenter_for_model_c_spec.rb
class ModelA < ActiveRecord::Base
  class ModelB < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
require_relative '../../../app/presenters/model_a/model_b/presenter_for_model_c'
```

since that would now force me to require ActiveRecord, which would defeat the purpose of the fast spec.

The only other solution I've come up with is to move the presenter to its own namespace `Presenters::ModelA::ModelB::PresenterForModelC`, where `Presenters::ModelA` and `Presenters::ModelB` would be modules and not classes. The downside to this approach, is that I would have to create a directory `app/presenters/presenters` in order for autoloading to work, which I think looks a little messy.

Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: Why are you nesting your ActiveRecord models like that? Looks very wrong and I suspect it may be confusing RSpec.

Comment: Good idea to namespace your stuff, makes things clear. No magic here: either you require all necessary files or you use `zeus` which I recommend to get your specs run directly